# Java HotSpot error

Tags: java, jvm, crash, jvm-hotspot

Curious if anyone could help out in regards to a Java HotSpot dump...saw some reference to head over to the Sun Forums, figured I would try here first...below is the dump...

```
#
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6d8c8f23, pid=2836, tid=5980
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (11.2-b01 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0xc8f23]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x06c4d800):  JavaThread "Thread-3365400" [_thread_in_vm, id=5980, stack(0x05560000,0x055b0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0x055ad9d0

Registers:
EAX=0x00002000, EBX=0x055afad4, ECX=0x055ad9d0, EDX=0x0556605c
ESP=0x055af9d8, EBP=0x055afb88, ESI=0x00000002, EDI=0x055af9d0
EIP=0x6d8c8f23, EFLAGS=0x00010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x055af9d8)
0x055af9d8:   06b54330 06c4d800 6d8c92fc 281db870
0x055af9e8:   055afa78 06c4d800 06b54320 06b54320
0x055af9f8:   0000000a 055afb90 06b54328 06b5432c
0x055afa08:   06b54330 00000005 06c4d800 06b54324
0x055afa18:   06c4d800 00000000 281db870 00000000
0x055afa28:   06b54330 00000000 00000000 00000000
0x055afa38:   6d951381 055afb88 055afa00 055afad4
0x055afa48:   00a190b0 06b54320 06c4d800 281db870 

Instructions: (pc=0x6d8c8f23)
0x6d8c8f13:   3b c6 7c 1c e8 74 51 08 00 0f af c6 8b cf 2b c8
0x6d8c8f23:   c7 01 00 00 00 00 a1 a4 18 a1 6d 46 3b f0 7e e4 


Stack: [0x05560000,0x055b0000],  sp=0x055af9d8,  free space=318k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0xc8f23]


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x06c45c00 JavaThread "Thread-3365408" [_thread_blocked, id=7184, stack(0x05510000,0x05560000)]
  0x03d7cc00 JavaThread "Thread-3365407" [_thread_blocked, id=8176, stack(0x05420000,0x05470000)]
=>0x06c4d800 JavaThread "Thread-3365400" [_thread_in_vm, id=5980, stack(0x05560000,0x055b0000)]
  0x03ed1400 JavaThread "SocketListener0-16" [_thread_blocked, id=6596, stack(0x05290000,0x052e0000)]
  0x06c96000 JavaThread "SocketListener0-6" [_thread_in_native, id=4880, stack(0x054c0000,0x05510000)]
  0x06c45000 JavaThread "SocketListener0-3" [_thread_blocked, id=6264, stack(0x05000000,0x05050000)]
  0x06c4a400 JavaThread "SocketListener0-22" [_thread_in_native, id=6612, stack(0x05380000,0x053d0000)]
  0x06da4400 JavaThread "pool-32-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=5440, stack(0x053d0000,0x05420000)]
  0x06c72800 JavaThread "pool-30-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=2156, stack(0x05050000,0x050a0000)]
  0x03f9cc00 JavaThread "pool-31-thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=2972, stack(0x05330000,0x05380000)]
  0x0370ac00 JavaThread "pool-31-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=5272, stack(0x052e0000,0x05330000)]
  0x06d32c00 JavaThread "pool-33-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=3244, stack(0x07e50000,0x07ea0000)]
  0x03ee8000 JavaThread "pool-29-thread-5" [_thread_blocked, id=5572, stack(0x05230000,0x05280000)]
  0x03fbac00 JavaThread "pool-29-thread-4" [_thread_blocked, id=3992, stack(0x051e0000,0x05230000)]
  0x06c56800 JavaThread "pool-29-thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=5256, stack(0x05190000,0x051e0000)]
  0x06c91400 JavaThread "pool-29-thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=4328, stack(0x05140000,0x05190000)]
  0x03b39800 JavaThread "pool-34-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=4424, stack(0x050f0000,0x05140000)]
  0x03d43800 JavaThread "Thread-3043484" [_thread_in_native, id=1660, stack(0x04fb0000,0x05000000)]
  0x06bad800 JavaThread "Timer-92" [_thread_blocked, id=5012, stack(0x04ba0000,0x04bf0000)]
  0x03740400 JavaThread "pool-29-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=5176, stack(0x04d80000,0x04dd0000)]
  0x06b3d400 JavaThread "0APRSeventListenThr" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4572, stack(0x050a0000,0x050f0000)]
  0x06c43400 JavaThread "Timer-90" [_thread_blocked, id=208, stack(0x04f60000,0x04fb0000)]
  0x03f3a800 JavaThread "Timer-89" [_thread_blocked, id=1132, stack(0x04f10000,0x04f60000)]
  0x06c97000 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-32" [_thread_blocked, id=5388, stack(0x04ec0000,0x04f10000)]
  0x0373f000 JavaThread "Timer-88" [_thread_blocked, id=5768, stack(0x04e70000,0x04ec0000)]
  0x06b6f800 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-31" [_thread_blocked, id=6140, stack(0x04e20000,0x04e70000)]
  0x03f4dc00 JavaThread "Timer-87" [_thread_blocked, id=4436, stack(0x04dd0000,0x04e20000)]
  0x03db8c00 JavaThread "Timer-85" [_thread_blocked, id=4820, stack(0x04d30000,0x04d80000)]
  0x06b4ec00 JavaThread "Timer-84" [_thread_blocked, id=5356, stack(0x04ce0000,0x04d30000)]
  0x03704c00 JavaThread "Timer-83" [_thread_blocked, id=3748, stack(0x04c90000,0x04ce0000)]
  0x03e7f000 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-30" [_thread_blocked, id=316, stack(0x04c40000,0x04c90000)]
  0x06b77c00 JavaThread "Timer-82" [_thread_blocked, id=1684, stack(0x04bf0000,0x04c40000)]
  0x03e13800 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-29" [_thread_blocked, id=5224, stack(0x04b50000,0x04ba0000)]
  0x038c0000 JavaThread "Timer-81" [_thread_blocked, id=4312, stack(0x04b00000,0x04b50000)]
  0x06cc7400 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-28" [_thread_blocked, id=2192, stack(0x04ab0000,0x04b00000)]
  0x06c21800 JavaThread "Timer-80" [_thread_blocked, id=1860, stack(0x04060000,0x040b0000)]
  0x03f33800 JavaThread "Timer-79" [_thread_blocked, id=3024, stack(0x04010000,0x04060000)]
  0x036f8800 JavaThread "Timer-78" [_thread_blocked, id=3088, stack(0x032b0000,0x03300000)]
  0x03f83000 JavaThread "SocketListener0-19" [_thread_in_native, id=2572, stack(0x05470000,0x054c0000)]
  0x02bbf800 JavaThread "0APRSeventListenThr" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5360, stack(0x04a60000,0x04ab0000)]
  0x033a8400 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-7" [_thread_blocked, id=2140, stack(0x04a10000,0x04a60000)]
  0x033a7c00 JavaThread "Timer-16" [_thread_blocked, id=3956, stack(0x049c0000,0x04a10000)]
  0x02c1b400 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-6" [_thread_blocked, id=5396, stack(0x04970000,0x049c0000)]
  0x0340d800 JavaThread "Timer-15" [_thread_blocked, id=5660, stack(0x04920000,0x04970000)]
  0x03a84000 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-5" [_thread_blocked, id=4164, stack(0x048d0000,0x04920000)]
  0x03a85400 JavaThread "Timer-14" [_thread_blocked, id=4836, stack(0x04880000,0x048d0000)]
  0x03b03000 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-4" [_thread_blocked, id=4480, stack(0x04830000,0x04880000)]
  0x03b06c00 JavaThread "Timer-13" [_thread_blocked, id=4264, stack(0x047e0000,0x04830000)]
  0x03a83000 JavaThread "pool-4-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=4316, stack(0x04790000,0x047e0000)]
  0x03202800 JavaThread "Timer-12" [_thread_blocked, id=4924, stack(0x04740000,0x04790000)]
  0x03204000 JavaThread "Timer-11" [_thread_blocked, id=1768, stack(0x046f0000,0x04740000)]
  0x03afa000 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=4036, stack(0x046a0000,0x046f0000)]
  0x03af5800 JavaThread "Timer-10" [_thread_blocked, id=2860, stack(0x04650000,0x046a0000)]
  0x03af3c00 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=1944, stack(0x04600000,0x04650000)]
  0x03af2c00 JavaThread "Timer-9" [_thread_blocked, id=2404, stack(0x045b0000,0x04600000)]
  0x03cbcc00 JavaThread "Timer-8" [_thread_blocked, id=2348, stack(0x04560000,0x045b0000)]
  0x03cba400 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=1348, stack(0x04510000,0x04560000)]
  0x03c9b800 JavaThread "Timer-7" [_thread_blocked, id=1972, stack(0x044c0000,0x04510000)]
  0x03c9a400 JavaThread "Timer-6" [_thread_blocked, id=4296, stack(0x04470000,0x044c0000)]
  0x03cab800 JavaThread "EventAdmin Async Event Dispatcher Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4276, stack(0x04420000,0x04470000)]
  0x03ca8800 JavaThread "Thread-12" [_thread_in_native, id=4336, stack(0x043d0000,0x04420000)]
  0x03912000 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=4452, stack(0x04380000,0x043d0000)]
  0x03432000 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=4612, stack(0x04330000,0x04380000)]
  0x03099c00 JavaThread "Timer-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4432, stack(0x042e0000,0x04330000)]
  0x03258c00 JavaThread "Timer-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4144, stack(0x04290000,0x042e0000)]
  0x03bc5400 JavaThread "Timer-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5984, stack(0x04240000,0x04290000)]
  0x03c72400 JavaThread "Timer-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4216, stack(0x041f0000,0x04240000)]
  0x03bc2400 JavaThread "Thread-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5780, stack(0x041a0000,0x041f0000)]
  0x03ad8c00 JavaThread "Timer-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3536, stack(0x04150000,0x041a0000)]
  0x03aedc00 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3760, stack(0x04100000,0x04150000)]
  0x0391f000 JavaThread "Worker-0" [_thread_blocked, id=3772, stack(0x040b0000,0x04100000)]
  0x038e6400 JavaThread "Acceptor ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,port=0,localport=9090]" [_thread_blocked, id=3116, stack(0x03fc0000,0x04010000)]
  0x038c2800 JavaThread "SessionScavenger" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3696, stack(0x03760000,0x037b0000)]
  0x03145000 JavaThread "Start Level Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3480, stack(0x03300000,0x03350000)]
  0x030dd000 JavaThread "ConsoleSocketGetter" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=568, stack(0x03260000,0x032b0000)]
  0x03104400 JavaThread "OSGi Console" [_thread_blocked, id=1252, stack(0x02fd0000,0x03020000)]
  0x03104000 JavaThread "Framework Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3152, stack(0x02f80000,0x02fd0000)]
  0x02b80c00 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1468, stack(0x02e30000,0x02e80000)]
  0x02b7b800 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5016, stack(0x02de0000,0x02e30000)]
  0x02b7a000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6052, stack(0x02d90000,0x02de0000)]
  0x02b78c00 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5332, stack(0x02d40000,0x02d90000)]
  0x02b70800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=980, stack(0x02cf0000,0x02d40000)]
  0x02b6f400 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1364, stack(0x02ca0000,0x02cf0000)]
  0x003a6c00 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=3712, stack(0x00990000,0x009e0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x02b6d800 VMThread [stack: 0x02c50000,0x02ca0000] [id=1864]
  0x02b83c00 WatcherThread [stack: 0x02e80000,0x02ed0000] [id=2712]

VM state:synchronizing (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x003a5968] UNKNOWN - owner thread: 0x02b6d800
[0x003a5dc8] UNKNOWN - owner thread: 0x06c45000

Heap
 def new generation   total 4544K, used 4177K [0x22990000, 0x22e70000, 0x22e70000)
  eden space 4096K, 100% used [0x22990000, 0x22d90000, 0x22d90000)
  from space 448K,  18% used [0x22e00000, 0x22e14460, 0x22e70000)
  to   space 448K,   0% used [0x22d90000, 0x22d90000, 0x22e00000)
 tenured generation   total 60544K, used 53242K [0x22e70000, 0x26990000, 0x26990000)
   the space 60544K,  87% used [0x22e70000, 0x2626e8a0, 0x2626ea00, 0x26990000)
 compacting perm gen  total 30720K, used 30550K [0x26990000, 0x28790000, 0x2a990000)
   the space 30720K,  99% used [0x26990000, 0x28765898, 0x28765a00, 0x28790000)
    ro space 8192K,  63% used [0x2a990000, 0x2aea7e48, 0x2aea8000, 0x2b190000)
    rw space 12288K,  53% used [0x2b190000, 0x2b7fcb38, 0x2b7fcc00, 0x2bd90000)

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00424000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\java.exe
0x7c800000 - 0x7c8c2000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
0x77e40000 - 0x77f42000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
0x7d1e0000 - 0x7d27c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x77c50000 - 0x77cef000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x76f50000 - 0x76f63000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\Secur32.dll
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\msvcr71.dll
0x6d800000 - 0x6da56000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x77380000 - 0x77411000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
0x77c00000 - 0x77c49000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
0x76aa0000 - 0x76acd000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
0x76290000 - 0x762ad000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x71bc0000 - 0x71bc8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rdpsnd.dll
0x771f0000 - 0x77201000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINSTA.dll
0x77ba0000 - 0x77bfa000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x71c40000 - 0x71c97000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\NETAPI32.dll
0x76b70000 - 0x76b7b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x6d290000 - 0x6d298000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\hpi.dll
0x6d7b0000 - 0x6d7bc000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\verify.dll
0x6d330000 - 0x6d34f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.dll
0x6d7f0000 - 0x6d7ff000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\zip.dll
0x68000000 - 0x68035000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x76920000 - 0x769e2000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USERENV.dll
0x6d610000 - 0x6d623000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\net.dll
0x71c00000 - 0x71c17000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x71bf0000 - 0x71bf8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2HELP.dll
0x71b20000 - 0x71b61000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\mswsock.dll
0x76ed0000 - 0x76efa000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x76f70000 - 0x76f77000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\winrnr.dll
0x76f10000 - 0x76f3e000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WLDAP32.dll
0x76f80000 - 0x76f85000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x6d630000 - 0x6d639000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\nio.dll
0x5f270000 - 0x5f2ca000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\hnetcfg.dll
0x71ae0000 - 0x71ae8000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x72000000 - 0x72012000     C:\Syntellect\ocs\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.0.3.R33x_v20080118\eclipse_1023.dll
0x77420000 - 0x77523000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.3790.3959_x-ww_D8713E55\COMCTL32.dll
0x77da0000 - 0x77df2000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x77b90000 - 0x77b98000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\VERSION.dll
0x6d790000 - 0x6d798000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\sunmscapi.dll
0x761b0000 - 0x76243000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x76190000 - 0x761a2000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSASN1.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xbootclasspath/a:c:\syntellect/ocs/plugins/stax2-api_3.0.1.jar;c:\syntellect/ocs/plugins/woodstox-core-asl_4.0.5.jar -Duser.dir=c:\syntellect -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:\C:\syntellect\ocs\plugins\com.syntellect.outbound.iom.apropos_0.0.1\lib\CHIPclient.jar 
java_command: c:\syntellect\ocs\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.1.R33x_v20080118.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\Tools;C:\Program Files\YourKit Java Profiler 7.0.12\bin\win32;
USERNAME=Administrator
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows Server 2003 family Build 3790 Service Pack 2

CPU:total 4 (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 15 stepping 7, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3

Memory: 4k page, physical 2096388k(757460k free), swap 3444692k(2457416k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (11.2-b01) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_12-b04), built on Jan 17 2009 09:57:14 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1

time: Thu Nov 19 01:55:36 2009
elapsed time: 126527 seconds
```

Comment: Best tell us what the code is doing. Do you have a JNI library?

Comment: How did you get that? And can it be reproduced. If it can't - ignore it. :)

Comment: It can be reproduced...this is our codebase...however it is generally 24+ hours into perf testing when this occurs. Essentially trying to figure out how to identify if this is indeed our issue that we need to deal with and if so where. No JNI is involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible you ran out of memory.  What are your -Xms -Xmx settings for the JVM?  I'd suggest setting them to be the same.  With the Hotspot JVM, I occasionally see crashes when it tries to increase the heap size.

1. It looks like your running a default sized JVM on Window (128MB).  Avoiding Windows would help, but something else you can do is allocate more memory.  Try setting your JVM to `-Xms512m -Xmx512m`
2. Setting the min and max memory ensures the heap is continuos and the JVM doesn't have to attempt to grow the heap.  This leads to a more stable JVM.
3. The process died in `jvm.dll`.  This is Sun's code, so they are the likely culprit, but is possible your external library corrupted the memory somewhere.
4. Your program is creating threads left, right, and centre.  You can tell by the thread names.  By default each thread gets a new sequentially numbered id.  The program could reuse the threads by making use of a `ThreadPool`.  The creation and collection of threads causes extra work for the JVM and OS.

Comment: Adjusting the memory settings apepared to do the trick, somehow we got narrow minded in that this was already done earlier when running as a service, however...in dev...cloudy viewpoint...forgot the simplest of things...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When I get unexpected segmentation violations, my first suspect is a third-party DLL. I see that you have one there, from SysIntellect. Is it something that you need to run? If not, then take it out of your classpath, and see if you still get the problem.

The crash appeared to have been triggered by a thread currently running JVM code (see "_thread_in_vm" in the thread listing), so it's possible that you've stumbled across a VM bug (but more likely that you're seeing memory corrupted by that third-party DLL).

On the off chance that it was a VM bug, I did a search on the [Sun Bug Parade](http://bugs.sun.com/), using the keywords "_thread_in_vm, jvm.dll+0xc8f23, 1.6.0_12-b04". No results returned, which indicates that either it's a rare bug or caused by outside interference. I mention the keywords because you'll generally see real bugs reporting the same PC ("jvm.dll+0xc8f23"), and it may be version-specific ("1.6.0_12-b04").

Good luck -- I've found that's the most helpful thing to say when faced with heap dumps.

---

Edit: you say that SysIntellect is your codebase, and it's clearly being loaded as a DLL, but in a comment above you say that you're not using JNI. In that case, how are you accessing the DLL?

If you can reproduce in a Linux environment, I'd recommend [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to try to find any invalid accesses.

Comment: The Syntellect component is our codebase...which is why narrowing in on who is responsible is critical...