# JVM crashes with illegal instruction in desktop Libgdx app

Tags: java, libgdx

I've been trying to start some development using libgdx, and have been following the setup tutorial. https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectSetupNew

However, when I try to run the desktop application, I get the following error:

```
    #
    # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION (0xc000001d) at pc=0x6cee60ce, pid=1908, tid=2912
    #
    # JRE version: 7.0_25-b17
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.25-b01 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
    # Problematic frame:
    # C  [gdx.dll+0x260ce]  Java_com_badlogic_gdx_graphics_g2d_Gdx2DPixmap_load+0xde
    #
    # Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
    #
    # An error report file with more information is saved as:
    # C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\my-gdx-game-desktop\hs_err_pid1908.log
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
    # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
    # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
    #
    AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
```

The android application runs fine however. I'm running Windows XP. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I've unable to find a solution elsewhere.

Comment: Which version of libgdx?

Comment: Probably irrelevant, but why running java on the Administrator account?

Comment: @noone Not really. The relevant part is about loading images.

Comment: Try JDK1.6.x, there are (old?) problems with LibGDX and JDK1.7.

Comment: Nightly build of libgdx, JDK 1.7. I'll give JDK1.6.x a try and see how it goes. Thanks
@Rekin: It's the only account I have set up on this machine.

Comment: Same problem with JDK 1.6.0_45. Same error message apart from the JRE Version line which now reads "6.0_45-b06"

Comment: Do any of the libgdx texture test apps run?  Maybe there is something funky in the image you're loading?  Or maybe gdx.dll is corrupted (you could try downloading it again...).

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1767277/1895303

Comment: libGDX 1.4.x actually says Java 1.6 *won't* work, so I would update your JDK.

Comment: Also, are you running any threads alongside your render thread? There are methods and objects that render() interacts with that are not thread safe and can cause these kinds of issues.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, this problem has been solved with the new versions of LibGDX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using new version of libGDX fixes this problem